# Improve neural network to identify sign language

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a dataset of 1680 images of sign language examples.
The dataset is divided to 7 users, each performing 10 times each of 24 englisg letters (without J and Z).
My goal is to identify which letter is presented.

I chose 6 users for train and one user for test.

My neural network looks like this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(24))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = split_train_test(images, users)
opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=30, epochs=10,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
).history
```

But the best accuracy I get is 80%.
Any Ideas how to improve?

Comment: That's a very interesting question. I'm not sure you'll find people on StackOverflow to answer you - perhaps pay https://ai.stackexchange.com/ a visit while you're at it. Good luck!

Comment: @Eusebius: Not a direct answer to your question, but it's worth noting that what you're talking about identifying here is *fingerspelling* (a manual encoding of words spelled out) and not *sign language* (which encompasses much more than that). Also, a fluent user of sign language is unlikely to spell each letter with anywhere near the clarity in your example image set; it is very common to "glide" from one letter to the next in a word without distinctly separating letters, not unlike how you can identify entire written words by their shapes even when central parts of the letters are obscured.

Answer (score 1):

1. Modifying the model

You can try to add some Conv2D layers, creating blocks of two Conv2D layers before each max pooling one. You can also try to reduce the kernel size of the last layers.

Here an example :

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(24))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))
```

2. More training

You can also try to train your network during more epochs, using the keras `ImageDataGenerator` to create new images from the ones you already have. That way, your model will have more data and may gain in accuracy.

Here is a link to this keras class : https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class